# Retrieve data from a class in Parse.com

Tags: android, database, parse-platform

I have a class in Parse.com, as XYZ, and it has columns email, password, phone, age. I have email and password combination and I want to check whether there is such a combination in the class? How do I do this?

I have a class Donate, and I have been given an email(e) and password(pw). Here goes the code:

```
`ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("donate");
            query.whereEqualTo("email", e);
            query.whereEqualTo("password", pw);
            query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
                @Override
                public void done(List<ParseObject> list, ParseException e) {
                    if (e == null) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Success!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Something went wrong!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            });                     `
```

And this always shows 'success' irrespective of the strings e, and pw.

Comment: Its not XYZ, it SHOULD be the Users class that stores the username and password. And you can login directly with the Parse API. Didn't you read at the documentation? If not, heres the link: https://www.parse.com/docs/android/guide

Comment: My app has three sections where user can login independently. For this, I am compelled to use custom classes, not the user one.

Comment: I have a class Donate, and I have been given an email and password. Here goes the code:

Comment: Code edited @kRiZ...

Answer (score 0):

**ParseQuery** return **ParseException** just if there was **technical issue** calling the server.
else, even though your **query doesn't find exactly what you looked for**,
it will return an **empty list** and the **'e' var** will be **null**.
so what you need to do is :

```
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("donate");
    query.whereEqualTo("email", e);
    query.whereEqualTo("password", pw);
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> list, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                if (list.isEmpty() == false) {   // add this
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Success!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Worng password!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); // add this

                }

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Something went wrong!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
```